# BigQuery Data transfer jobs failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-transfer

BigQuery data transfer job failed with following error message.

"*Error code 7 : Invalid account; The issue may be resolved by verifying that the user has sufficient permissions and updating the credentials for this transfer config; error: "invalid_grant" error_description: "Invalid account"*"

As mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer, required permissions are given to the service account used for the transfer. Still getting this error.

Comment: Updated the user credentials and the issue resolved

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Could you please add the steps you followed as an answer for this post and accept it so other users with a similar issue can use your solution?

Comment: I changed the user credentials with a new service account having necessary permission to the job

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by OP by updating the user credentials with a new service account having the necessary permissions for the job, according to [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#required_permissions)

Comment: @SKumar How did you refresh the credentials to a service account? For me its taking me to google sign in page

Comment: how to add service account from console?

Comment: @Sam at present we cannot refresh the credential from Console. We need to use Cloud Shell. [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#update_scheduled_query_credentials)

`code`bq update --transfer_config --update_credentials --service_account_name=<service-account-name> <job’s transfer config>

Comment: I ended up tainting the resource in terraform so that its recreated with the correct credentials